# New cooktop has aluminum wires

Tags: electrical

New cooktop has aluminum wires. Is it ok to connect those wires to the present outlet which had copper wires connecting the old cooktop?
Thank you for your help

Comment: A picture would help.

Answer (score 4):

I will all but guaranty you the wires are not aluminum, but tinned copper. Look at the cut ends of the conductors, not the stripped part. Tell us what you find.